# Foreach loop and placeholders

Tags: asp.net

I have a placeholder in my .aspx file

When i add controls to in in the .aspx.cs file i also add some literal controls in addition to some tableboxes and labels, as such

```
        phOutputs.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<tr><td>"));
        phOutputs.Controls.Add(lbl1);
        phOutputs.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</td><td>"));
        phOutputs.Controls.Add(tbx1);
        phOutputs.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</td></tr>"));
```

Down the road i tried using a `foreach` loop as like this

`foreach (TextBox tbxInput in phOutputs.Controls)`

but i get cast exceptions on run time saying you cant convert LiteralControl to tablebox.

What would be a better way of doing this?

Comment: what is `phInputs` actually?

Comment: That was another placeholder.  I pasted wrong one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is because your collection contains not only textboxes.
OfType extension can be used for filtering.

```
foreach (TextBox tbxInput in phOutputs.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
{
}
```

Also as alternative - you can make a cast to a base class WebControl (instead of TextBox) in your foreach, but it depends on what you want to do in this loop. For sure, if you need textbox specific properties - this variant won't do.

Comment: Thanks all, these are all good answers... hard to pick the best one

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to just loop over textboxes, you can use Linq to select only the controls that *are* textboxes and then iterate over those instead:

```
foreach(TextBox tbxInput in phOutputs.Controls.Where(o => o is TextBox))
```

Voila; no `InvalidCastException`.

Comment: oh cool, yeah something like that is what i was looking for.  I'll try it thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should first check whether the control is of type `TextBox` or not and then cast it to Textbox accordingly

```
foreach (control crtl in phInputs.Controls)
{
if(crtl is TextBox )
{
 TextBox txt = (TextBox )crtl;
}
}
```